# FullCalendar Event has too much top/bottom padding around the event time/title

Tags: fullcalendar

I am new to FullCalendar, downloaded and added to a php project. Added an event (hardcoded) as per the examples and it shows great except, the height of the event is so tall. It looks like there is padding above and below the text, nothing like all the examples I have seen where the events are nice thin blocks.

I have researched and found code to lower the height of the events but, when I do this it cuts off the bottom of the event time and title.

For example, I added .fc-event { height: 1em; } and it makes the events look more the all the examples BUT as I mentioned, it only cuts the event bottom and cuts off the bottom of the time and title (cannot read the event).

Here is a link to images http://snappdf.tumblr.com/

Answer (score -1):

Using .fc-event changes the CSS for all events on your calendar. You might prefer using the className attribute of the event instead. This way you can customize individual events without impact.

Also, please post some code or better a jsfiddle to better understand the problem.

Comment: Hi ganeshk, I will investigate the className attribute. I have no code to show because it is just how the events are showing up on my calendar as installed.

Comment: Hi, I have added a link to show the default event sizes from installation AND also me trying to use className to modify the event size (month view) and how it's cutting off the text.....[images]http://snappdf.tumblr.com/

Comment: I know what you are looking for. Could you post the CSS class that you used with className?

Comment: .myEvent{
        height: 1em;
        margin-top: 1px;
        font-size: small;
 }

Comment: Hi ganeshk, I think I have some other css interfering with my FullCalendar css. I removed all my css that is not related to FullCalendar and I was able to get the events to appear correctly!! Thank you for you time and help!!

Comment: Found it!! Under my css body I had "line-height: 180%;" which effected my event heights and fonts....removed this and they are okay.